# Getting 'Access Denied' exception on S3 putObject

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm trying to write a byte array to an S3 bucket using Java sdk2 (software.amazon.awssdk:s3), but I can't get it to work - I constantly get access denied errors. Here's what I have:

A very permissive policy:

```
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:896591375297:accesspoint/*",
                "arn:aws:s3::896591375297:accesspoint/*",
                "arn:aws:s3-object-lambda:*:896591375297:accesspoint/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:896591375297:job/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:us-west-2:896591375297:async-request/mrap/*/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:896591375297:storage-lens/*"
            ]
        }
```

And some code:

```
    public void saveCA(String orgId, String certId, byte[] caData) {

      PutObjectRequest req = PutObjectRequest.builder()
          .bucket("cacache-bucket")   // tried the ARN here (no banana). Bucket exists
          .key(certId)   // certId is to be the object name
          .build();

      RequestBody body = RequestBody.fromBytes(caData);
      client.putObject(req, body);
    }
```

And the error:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: Access Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: RQH01Z7PJ54YDSAV, Extended Request ID: vJRt...
```

Any ideas?

thanks,

Jim

Comment: Hi Jim, I recommend that you allow all the permissions in the bucket settings. Afterward, you can gradually change it to your production settings step by step. This way, you can understand which part caused the problem.

Comment: Does the S3 bucket also have a bucket policy that could be overriding these IAM permissions? Ditto, is there an organization-level SCP? Have you double-checked that you are using the AWS credentials you think you are using (call STS GetCallerIdentity)?

Comment: Credentials are fine, I'm accessing Kms and dynamodb with them a few steps beforehand. I think that policy allows the user full access to s3 (am I right?), Not sure about an overriding policy, it's a more or less new Aws account - will have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Could you try to do a `aws s3 cp <LocalPath> <S3Uri>` from the same machine to see the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working... points that are pretty obvious but I couldn't establish from the docs:

- bucket is just the name - not s://bucket, not the URN
- key is the name to save it under. you can add folders that don't exist, no leading slash - eg "folder/file"
- regenerating the credentials after I'd updated the user's policies may have helped, not sure

Thanks for the advice though - testing with AWS cli especially.